# login to website with curl and download webpage

Tags: windows, website, authentication, curl

i am trying to log-in into a website and download a webpage.
**do not be alarmed- the website and credentials are public knowledge**...

anyway, my code is as follows:

```
curl -k https://url.retail.publishedprices.co.il/login > 01.txt

sfk xed 01.txt "_[start][0.10000 bytes]csrftoken__" +xed "_/>**__" +xed "_\q id=\qcsrftoken\q value=\q__" +xed "_\q __" -tofile 02.txt

set /p csrf=<02.txt

curl -k -d "username=retalix&password=12345&csrftoken=%csrf%" https://url.retail.publishedprices.co.il/file/d/RamiLevi/ > RL.txt
```

what the code does is download the login page, extract the csrf variable and use it, plus the username/password, to log-in another sub-"domain" in the same website.

**the end result should be a webpage that is saved into "RL.txt"** but none of the solutions i could find worked and i can't understand why.

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What version of windows are you using?, are you restricted to using curl/sfk? Would you consider powershell?

Comment: windows 10 LTSB/C. a solution using powershell is fine. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was working on something similar at the time I quickly put this together for you:

Please change the path and filename to your requirements, make sure that the path has a trailing slash.

```
$path = "c:\test\"
$filename = "website.txt"

$url = "https://url.retail.publishedprices.co.il/login"
$url2 = "https://url.retail.publishedprices.co.il/file/d/RamiLevi/"

$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application

$ie.visible = $true
$ie.silent = $false

$ie.navigate("$url")

while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100}
if ($ie.document.url -Match "invalidcert"){
    $sslbypass=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") | where-object {$_.id -eq "overridelink"}
    $sslbypass.click()
    start-sleep -s 5
}

$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("username").click()
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("username").value ='retalix'
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("password").click()
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("password").value ='12345'
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("submit").click()

start-sleep 5

$ie.navigate($url2)

start-sleep 10

$ie.Document.body.outerHTML | Out-File -FilePath $path$filename
```

This takes around 25 seconds to run due to the start-sleeps, this is to allow the pages to load. Depending on your connection you may need to increase these.

After you have ran the script and are happy with the outcome you can then do the following.

Change the following so that IE does not open up on the desktop:

```
$ie.visible = $true
```

to

```
$ie.visible = $false
```

and add the following at the end of the script to ensure IE closes at the end:

```
$ie.quit()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ... and how do you run it? ;-)